# How do i create a MongoDb database for logging?

Tags: mongodb, logging

For context i am comparing NoSQL vs SQL for my logging database.

In my SQL Database i have 8 tables:

- Machines: the different machines connected
- MachineDataLogs: sensor data from machines, foreign key to machines
- Groups: the different groups under a machine, foreign key to machines
- GroupDataLogs: sensor data for groups, foreign key to groups and machines
- Units: the different units under a group, foreign key to groups and machines
- UnitDataLogs: sensor data for units, foreign key to units, groups and machines
- Components: the different components under a unit, foreign key to units, groups and machines
- ComponentDataLogs: sensor data for components, foreign key to components, units, groups and machines

Now i want to make something similar in MongoDb. But i am not sure where to start.

Should i create a machine collection and nest all logs inside a single object?
Logs will be added every 30 - 1 second for multiple machines. so these objects would become huge.

Or should i create a machine, group, unit and component collection with their logs inside?

Or should i create a collection for every SQL table?

Queries i would do:

- get machinedatalogs between a certain time
- get machinedatalogs + groupdatalogs between a certain time
- get machinedatalogs + groupdatalogs + unitdatalogs between a certain time
- get machinedatalogs + groupdatalogs + unitdatalogs + componentdatalogs between a certain time
- get machinedatalogs ordered DESC. (newest entry first)
- get machinedatalogs + groupdatalogs ordered DESC. (newest entry first)
- get machinedatalogs + groupdatalogs + unitdatalogs ordered DESC. (newest entry first)
- get machinedatalogs + groupdatalogs + unitdatalogs + componentdatalogs ordered DESC. (newest entry first)

Comment: Have you considered just ELK with Kibana integration? Or Logs.IO as a cloud-based solution if it's applicable to your system... Usually, people use this combination instead of re-inventing the logging system... Of course, I don't know your situation but seems to me too much effort (think about convenient visualization, data base management, etc).

Comment: Usually a NoSQL database like MongoDB has much less collections than according application in SQL database. NoSQL databases are not optimized for joins, some NoSQL databases even do not support joins at all.